# empty files are being decompressed and extracted

Tags: c++, linux, gzip, 7zip, libarchive

i have compressed few files using following format and filter through libarchive in linux environment

```
arch = archive_write_new();
archive_write_add_filter_gzip(arch);
archive_write_set_format_7zip(arch);
archive_write_open_filename(arch, outname)
```

archive and compression was successful and when i extract and decompress the files in windows using 7z tool i see some of the files are empty. Can any one please help me on this
libarchive version: 3.3.2

Comment: "when i extract and decompress the files in windows using 7z tool i see some of the files are empty" - seems perfectly reasonable if they were empty prior to being compressed.

Comment: i had checked in linux machine manually, files are not empty. They have contents in it.